# Retrieving cookie with every load of Single Page App

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**What specific changes need to be made to the AngularJS code below to check for the existence of a cookie named `myCookie` every time a page is loaded, and then to set the `$rootScope.myCookieValue` variable to become the value of `myCookie`?**

The code is from [the sample app whose complete code you can explore at this link](https://github.com/spring-guides/tut-spring-security-and-angular-js/blob/master/oauth2/ui/src/main/resources/static/js/hello.js).  It is a very simple example app, and I just want a simple working solution to this so that I can build up more complex approaches from it.

```
angular.module('hello', [ 'ngRoute' ]).config(function($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl : 'home.html',
        controller : 'home',
        controllerAs : 'controller'
    }).otherwise('/');

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';

}).controller('navigation',

function($rootScope, $http, $location, $route) {

    var self = this;

    self.tab = function(route) {
        return $route.current && route === $route.current.controller;
    };

    $http.get('user').then(function(response) {
        if (response.data.name) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
        } else {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        }
    }, function() {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
    });

    self.credentials = {};

    self.logout = function() {
        $http.post('logout', {}).finally(function() {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            $location.path("/");
        });
    }

}).controller('home', function($http) {
    var self = this;
    $http.get('resource/').then(function(response) {
        self.greeting = response.data;
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in run block I guess:

```
 angular.module('hello', ['ngCookies', 'ngRoute'])

.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'home',
        controllerAs: 'controller'
    }).otherwise('/');

    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['Accept'] = 'application/json';

}).run(function ($rootScope, $cookies) {
    var cookieValue = $cookies.get("myCookie");
    if (cookieValue) {
        $rootScope.myCookieVar = cookieValue;
    }
}).controller('navigation',

function ($rootScope, $http, $location, $route) {

    var self = this;

    self.tab = function (route) {
        return $route.current && route === $route.current.controller;
    };

    $http.get('user').then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.name) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = true;
        } else {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
        }
    }, function () {
        $rootScope.authenticated = false;
    });

    self.credentials = {};

    self.logout = function () {
        $http.post('logout', {}).finally(function () {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            $location.path("/");
        });
    }

}).controller('home', function ($http) {
    var self = this;
    $http.get('resource/').then(function (response) {
        self.greeting = response.data;
    })
});
```

I think you should use angular version > 1.4.x

you should also add reference angular-cookies.js

Comment: OK.  **At what location in the code from the OP should I place the `run` block?**  Thank you for the version advice.  I am just putting together a simple example to connect other things with this.  I will upgrade to Angular 2 and make other changes later.

Comment: since you want to do something when your application want to start, I suggest that you put this `run` block in your top module, and in the code you provided this `module` is the `hello` module. simply attach the `run` block to your module...

Comment: The angular app stops loading in the browser after I add it where I think you indicated.  And the FireFox debugger does not show `hello.js` anymore after the change, so I am not able to debug.

Comment: I think the problem has to do with locations of `)` and `}` etc.  Do you mind please pasting your code into the OP code in your answer, so the precise syntax is clear?  Thank you.

Comment: @FirstOfMany I guess I fixed it.

Comment: It does not work.  The problem might have to do with additional injection of `$rootScope` and `ngCookies`/`$cookies`, into the top module, but none of my experiments are getting it to load in the browser.  Your example ends with a `;`, when I think you are saying to put it before `.controller(...`  Can you please copy the OP code into your answer, and show where your code should be inserted, along with any dependency injections?  Thank you.

Comment: The FireFox debugger now works, and it indicates that **the control flow never enters the run block.**  The debugger stops at the `.run...` line and then moves elsewhere, and then eventually stops without loading the app.  When I comment out the new run block, the app loads again.

Comment: No.  It does not work.  The complete app is on GitHub.  If you were willing to `git clone` it and `mvn spring-boot:run`, you could recreate this on your machine in a few minutes.

Comment: @FirstOfMany Just to remind you, we **won't** write code for you, we'll help you find a solution by giving you hints, links and etc. If you show us what you tried we can help you try to fix it.